# Running scheduled web scripts in a Windows Server environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis, scheduled-task

I'm trying to get a scheduled web script running on a Windows Server and so far the only way I've managed to automate this process is by using the Task Scheduler to open Internet Explorer with the web address as a parameter. I then need to create a separate task to run just after this task to close Internet Explorer (otherwise the task doesn't complete).

Is there a better way of doing this?

I've also managed to run the script by calling the web address through a Telnet connection to the web server (GET /web/address/here) but I haven't found a way of automating this process on a scheduled basis.

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post as I see is essentially a duplicate of this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947142/open-url-from-script-on-windows-server-2008

There he got quite a few answers right up your alley (most notably some PowerShell scripts).

Comment: The vbscript + Task Scheduler seems to work well. Must have missed this one :) Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've recently moved all stuff like this to a powershell script that calls a URL or does stuff with the .NET framework, then schedule with Task Scheduler

Answer (score -1):

THere are version of wget & curl for Windows (look for GnuWin32).  As commandline tools these could take many actions for you and exit.

Comment: Are there any ways of doing this using the standard Windows Server tools (like Telnet, Powershell, etc.)? Many thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.